# Displaying Combinations within an SSRS Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, matrix

I have the following data in my dataset

```
  Type | Code | Value
  C1   |      | Cash
  C2   |      | Check
  P1   | 0001 | Payment 1
  P2   | 0002 | Payment 2
```

that I need to use to create the following matrix

```
  P1 0001 
  P1 0001 Cash
  P1 0001 Check
  P1 0001 Cash Check
  P2 0002
  P2 0002 Cash
  P2 0002 Check
  P2 0002 Cash Check
```

Basically I need a way to show all the combinations of P Types and C Types but can't seem to get the column or row groups correct and am looking for some help. Thanks.

SSRS Version = 2008 R2 if it makes a difference

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far, and what specific problems you had with your current solutions?

Comment: The C types look like types of payments whereas the P types look like actual payments which are of C types. Can you elaborate on your database schema and show what SQL you have so far?

Comment: Your data bears no resemblance to your desired output.  I think you are wasting your time trying to fix that using SSRS grouping.  You should probably go back and redesign your dataset to suit your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a different route on this. Instead of building out the matrix in SSRS, I wrote a sql function that builds out the matrix and returns a table. SSRS just calls the function and grabs all the rows.